# Python asynchronous call that updates a variable

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-multithreading

I have a function `def act(obs)` that returns a float and is computationally expensive (takes some time to run).

```py
import time
import random

def act(obs):
    time.sleep(5) # mimic computation time
    action = random.random()
    return action
```

I regularly keep calling this function in a script faster than how long it takes for it to execute. I do not want any waiting time when calling the function. Rather I prefer using the returned value from an earlier computation. How do I achieve this?

Something I have thought of is having a global variable that updated in the function and I keep reading the global variable although I am not sure if that is the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70556373/8878627)

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_updating = False
        self.result = -1
    
    def _act(self, obs):
        self.is_updating = True
        time.sleep(5)
        self.result = obs
        self.is_updating = False
        
    def act(self, obs):
        if not self.is_updating:
            threading.Thread(target=self._act, args=[obs]).start()
        return self.result

agent = MyClass()

i = 0
while True:
    agent.act(obs=i)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i, agent.result)
    i += 1
```

Comment: There are race conditions and unsynchronized accesses to shared data. Yes, you can use threads for this, but no, it's not that easy. For a start, document what guarantees this thing gives, because only then you can really reason about whether this works or not. Also, injecting the wrapped function would help, both to make it more universally useful but also to allow testing it in isolation.

Comment: "injecting the wrapped function would help" what do you mean by this? Please link an example if possible :)

Comment: I meant passing it to the constructor. Research the term "dependency injection" for further inspiration. Also, you could turn this into a Python decorator.

Answer (score 0):

The global variable way should work, Also you can have a class that has a private member let's say `result` and a flag `isComputing` and a method `getResult` which would call a method `compute()`(via a thread) if it is not computing currently, and returns the previous result. The `compute()` method should update the flag `isComputing` properly.